# VBA How can I repeat code on every slide to edit the FIRST text box?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, powerpoint, simpledateformat

I am writing a VB code for Powerpoint. It retrieves a date from the SECOND Text box on the slide and calculates the amount of days until this date. Then the calculated amount of days is shown in the FIRST text box. I can not get the code to repeat for the second slide, although the textboxes are named the same thing as the first slide.

```
'Sets variables
Dim Sdate As Long
Dim thedate As Date
Dim txt As Date
Dim pptSlide3 As Slide

Do
 For Each pptSlide3 In ActivePresentation.Slides

   Set sld = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide

 'Retrieves D-Day from corresponding text box


  TextBox2.Font.Size = 36
   thedate = TextBox2.Text

'Calculates the amount of time from today's date until D-day above
Sdate = DateDiff("d", Now(), thedate)

'Creates textbox with the value of how many days are left
TextBox1.Value = Sdate & "  Days to go!"
TextBox1.Font.Size = 36

'Want it to wait 5 seconds here
   ' Goes to next slide

With SlideShowWindows(1).View
    If sld.SlideIndex < 4 Then
    .GotoSlide (sld.SlideIndex + 1)
    End If

    If sld.SlideIndex = 4 Then
    .GotoSlide (1)
    End If
End With

  Next pptSlide3
  Loop
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this instead:

```
Do
 For Each pptSlide3 In ActivePresentation.Slides

 'Retrieves D-Day from corresponding text box

  TextBox2.Font.Size = 36
  thedate = pptSlide3.Shapes("TextBox2").OLEFormat.Object.Text

'Calculates the amount of time from today's date until D-day above
Sdate = DateDiff("d", Now(), thedate)

'Creates textbox with the value of how many days are left
pptSlide3.Shapes("TextBox1").OLEFormat.Object.Text = Sdate & "  Days to go!"
TextBox1.Font.Size = 36

'Want it to wait 5 seconds here
   ' Goes to next slide

With SlideShowWindows(1).View
    If pptSlide3.SlideIndex < 4 Then
    .GotoSlide (pptSlide3.SlideIndex + 1)
    End If

    If pptSlide3.SlideIndex = 4 Then
    .GotoSlide (1)
    End If
End With

  Next pptSlide3
  Loop
```

Comment: Works, thanks ! I'll have to look into OLEFormat.. Any chance you know how to put a five second delay in? sleep wasn't working for me. Thanks again

Comment: I used the following as a timer.. .

     `Start = Timer`
        `While Timer < Start + 5 ` 
       `DoEvents`
      `Wend`

Comment: Just to fill in a blank or two:  when you have an ActiveX control on a slide, the shape's OLEFormat.Object gives you access to the same properties you'd get from the same shape on a Form. Unfortunately, Intellisense doesn't kick in to help, but you can rightclick the shape and choose Properties to see what properties are available and what they're called.